# Returning an array of only odd numbers

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need to return an array of only the odd numbers, e.g. `[1,3,5]`. I've been asked to do this as part of my schooling and I cant see where I'm going wrong.

```
public static int[] odds(int numOdds) {
    int[] odds = numOdds;
    for (int i=0; i<odds.length; i++) {
        if (odds[i] %2 != 0) {
            return odds;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] theOdds = odds(3);
    System.out.println(theOdds[0] + ", " + theOdds[1] + ", " + theOdds[2]);
}
```

Comment: What does the compiler error message say? Have you read it? Does it sound fine to store an int inside a variable whose type is not int, but int[]? Does it look normal for your code to never store anything in the array? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: You're assigning an integer to an array of integers. Change to `int[] odds = new int[numOdds];`

Comment: The compiler even tells you exactly what's wrong. If you throw up your hands at the first sign of trouble, you're never going to learn anything. It's important to struggle with problems in order to learn.

Comment: you are passing `int` value to the method. Do you want first three odd numbers? OR do you want to pass an integer array with some numbers and pick only the odd numbers from them. Clarify that in your question pls.

Comment: thanks for your comments. ive been reading that and I simply cant my head around it and my "mentor" isn't really giving me the time to explain for me to understand.

numOdds is actually a positive integer representing the number of odd numbers I have to to store in the array

Comment: okay. so who is providing the numbers to filter through in your code?

Comment: im providing int[] theOdds = odds(3); as a test at the moment but they will eventually be feed in automatically from an external system and ive to extract the odd numbers

Comment: If an external system is going to provide an array of numbers, how will you know how large to make your target array?  The number of odd values will be unknown.

Comment: no im returning an array from a positive integer which is passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code as posted.  See my comments below

```java
public static int[] odds(int numOdds) {
    //   int[] odds = numOdds;     // needs to be int[] odds = new int[numOdds] to 
                                   //store the values.  It is the array you will 
                                   // return.
    int[] odds = new int[numOdds];

    int start = 1;            // you need to have a starting point
    for (int i=0; i<odds.length; i++) {
    //    if (odds[i] %2 != 0) { // don't need this as you are generating odd 
                                 // numbers yourself


    //    return odds;      // You're doing this too soon.  You need to store 
                               // the numbers in the array first 

          odds[i] = start;  // store the first odd number
          start += 2;       // this generates the next odd number.  Remember that
                            // every other number is even or odd depending from
                            // where you start.

    }
    return odds;         // now return the array of odd numbers.

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] theOdds = odds(3);
    System.out.println(theOdds[0] + ", " + theOdds[1] + ", " + theOdds[2]);
}
```

Comment: that you for this. the explanation is excellent for me to understand the rational here I was missing. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna return odds from an array you should pass it as parameter first, aslo you should store your odds in a new array after the IF statement.
You should use at the first time a dynamic list becouse you don't know how many odds are there, after you can easely convert the ArrayList to a normal Array. 
Something like this:

```
public static int[] odds(int[] arrayOfNumber) {

List<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i=0; i<arrayOfNumber.length; i++) {
    if (arrayOfNumber[i] %2 != 0) {
        odds.add(arrayOfNumber[i]);
    }
  }
  return odds.toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save time this way with native Java 8 streams API :

```
int[] odds = Arrays.stream(arrayOfNumbers).filter(number -> number%2 != 0).toArray();
```

Streams provides many methods to make your job quick